# Speed of a Function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using several functions, 14 to be exact, similar to the ones below, triggered by a change to the spreadsheet:

```
function principleHours(event){
  var Col = 53; 

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == Col) {

    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),Col);
    var comments = adjacent.getComments();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
     if (comments == "") {
       comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); 
     }
    else if (comments != "") {
     comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent();
     } 
  }
}


function principalTravel(event){
  var Col = 66; 

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == Col) {

    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),Col);
    var comments = adjacent.getComments();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
     if (comments == "") {
       comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); 
     }
    else if (comments != "") {
     comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent();
     } 
  }
}
```

Does it make sense to combine them into a single function? Is there an advantage to keeping them separated?

Comment: It looks like the two functions shown are identical except for the column number.  I would definitely consolidate the functions in this case.  Pass the column number to the function.   A major reason to consolidate is "maintenance."  If you need/want to make a change, with consolidated code, you just need to change it in one place.  Currently, you would need to edit every function, which is tedious, and something could get missed.  Consolidating the code will decrease the size of the file, which probably doesn't matter much as far as speed.  In your case I don't see any issue of speed.

Comment: Apps Script server code will run multiple instances simultaneously.  If multiple functions are being called simultaneously or in rapid succession, then each function is running one instance.  If the functions are consolidated into one function, and it gets called multiple times close together, it would mean that the same function would be running multiple instances at the same time, which shouldn't cause a slow down, but if it were hundreds of calls to the same function, it might be worth testing it either way.  That's the only situation I can think of that might affect the speed.

Comment: about the comment above: doubt it matters because the rate limit is about concurrent script calls, not per function. makes no difference speed or rate limit-wise to have one or two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will agree with the commenters and am surprised that it's not submitted as an answer.

I would recommend not calling multiple functions with an "onEdit" trigger if you can avoid it. The 2 functions so far seem to be more or less identical. If the only difference between your functions is the `Col` variable then I would recommend to do a slight edit, where you have 1 function perform the operation and have the `onEdit` call a new function that will call the single function and send different `Col` variables. This will mean that any adjustments you need to make to what your functions do is going to be on a single function.

Generally speaking you should use a function if it is shared code base. So if in your example

```
function foo(Col) {
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
    if (changedRange.getColumn() == Col) {

      var state = changedRange.getValue();
      var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),Col);
      var comments = adjacent.getComments();
      var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time
      // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
       if (comments == "") {
         comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
         adjacent.setComment(comments);
         changedRange.clearContent(); 
       }
      else if (comments != "") {
       comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
       adjacent.setComment(comments);
       changedRange.clearContent();
      } 
  }
}
```

is something you do in all functions then in the base code all you have to do is

```
function main() {
  foo(53)
  foo(66)
  //as many foo calls as you need
}
```

Try to use functions as a single bit of code that you can keep reusing and your `onEdit` will be your `main()`